# Error while connecting from Remix via rpc to local blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, remix

```
geth --datadir  ./accnt1   --port 30306 --networkid 2018 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain=”*” --nodiscover --rpcapi “db,personal,eth,net,web3,debug”  --rpcaddr="127.0.0.1" --rpcport 8545 console
```

using the above command to start the console , to connect remix to private blockchain .Even Tried localhost for rpcaddr . Also used http version of [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js). Still getting below error .

**Not possible to connect to the Web3 provider. Make sure the provider is running and a connection is open (via IPC or RPC).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure you have changed the environment in remix to Web3 provider
- while starting geth if you want to connect it to remix then you need to allow remote connections to ethereum node . That can be done by adding --rpccorsdomain "URL OF THE WEBSITE "
- the capital words in the below command means that you need to specify as required.

  geth --datadir="DIRECTORY OF THE GENESIS BLOCK" --rpc --rpcport PORTNUMBER  --rpccorsdomain "URL OF THE WEBSITE"

sample :
    geth --datadir="." --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcapi="miner,web3,debug,net,eth" console 2>>logger.log

- rpc allows HTTP over it and not HTTPS so in the url change https to http://remix.ethereum.org/ and the ide should be connected via http not via https . Use the link provided in this line to get connected to the ide.

Comment: So instead of * , I need to give localhost:8545   for the url  ?

Comment: or the url of the remix IDE

Comment: In the remix u should give http://localhost: PORTNUMBER  and in --rpccorsdomain u need to give url of remix

Comment: did you tested the command, because  am still getting the same issue .Moreover `--rpccorsdomain=”*”` covers all scenarios , right ?
This is the new command I am using
`geth --datadir  ./accnt1   --port 30306 --networkid 2018 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain=”http://remix.ethereum.org” --nodiscover --rpcapi “db,personal,eth,net,web3,debug”  --rpcaddr="127.0.0.1" --rpcport 8545 console`

Comment: yeah rpccorsdomain="*" covers all scenarios. But it is not working sometimes. That is why i asked u to mention it specifically

Comment: I am already using http version of remix , just see the command I am using , in above comment .Can u pls try that in ur machine ?